# Serializing System.Exception class by ignoring Data property serialization

Tags: c#, .net, exception, serialization

I am trying to serialize the System.Exception class of the .Net class library, however as many members have discussed before here, there is a problem with the Data property of the class because it implements the IDictionary interface, which makes it not serializable.

I am trying to override and mark this property to be ignored during serialization to solve the issue, but with no success, I am still receiving the same error.

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    [IgnoreDataMemberAttribute]
    public override IDictionary Data
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Data;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried using the IgnoreXML attribute with the same results, I am using the XMLSerializer class.

Answer (score 0):

To Serilalize IDictionary. Please try this:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class CustomException : Exception
{

    IDictionary _iDictionary;

    [DataMember]
    public override IDictionary Data
    {
        get
        {
            if (_iDictionary == null)
            {
                _iDictionary = base.Data;
            }
            return _iDictionary;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it gave the same exception telling that it couldn't serialize IDictionary.

Comment: I updated this example, add items to Data and wrote them to a file using a file stream. I think this is what you want.

Comment: still same problem, actually marking the Data property as DataMember tell the serializer to serialize it, which we want to avoid.

Comment: I'm confused, you want the dictionary to be serialized or not, regardless of the IDictionary implementation? What is the end goal?

Comment: The end goal is to serialize Exception class or a child of it. Whenever I try to do this I get an exception saying that IDictionary is not serializable that's why I am try to find a way to tell the serializer to skip it during the serialization process.

Comment: My example accomplishes this goal. Just make data null if you don't want its values. If you initialize and serialize CustomException it works per my example.

Comment: Still get the same exception whenever I try to serialize CustomException class.